# VBA Excel Adjusting Row Height

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a report in Excel and I would like VBA to format the row height based upon the value in column K.   For example, if cell K17 = 11.25, I want row 17 to be 11.25. Cell k18 = 21.75 so row 18 =21.75.

I need vba to change every row from 17-400.

This should be relatively simple but I can't seem to come up with the correct coding.

Comment: please post the code *you did come with* so that we can assist you in getting what you need.

Comment: look at loops, also, record yourself doing it, then look at the code.  What you need to do is loop something you can macro record and then decifer, thats how a lot of us learnt :)  There is no real question there to answer

Comment: I can record the loop with a macro but I am entering the height value manually which doesn't help.  What I can't do is get the code to look at the dynamic cell  in column K.   Yes, you are correct that I need help with looping.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an easy one, I went ahead and provided the answer for you:

```
Sub RowHeight()

Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("mySheet") 'replace with your sheet name

Dim rCell as Range
For each rCell in ws.Range("K17:K400")

     rCell.EntireRow.RowHeight = rCell.Value

Next

End Sub
```